# What is the easiest way to convert a Boost MultiArray (2d) to a normal 2d-array?

Tags: c++, arrays, boost

Is there a best/easiest way of converting a 2D Boost MultiArray to a normal 2D-array other than preallocating and iterating through all the elements?

```
#include "boost/multi_array.hpp"
#include <cassert>

int main () 
{
  // Create 2D multi-array
  typedef boost::multi_array<double, 2> array_type;
  typedef array_type::index index;
  array_type A(boost::extents[3][4]);

  // Fill in some values ...
  double value = 1.0;
  for(index i = 0; i != 3; ++i) 
    for(index j = 0; j != 4; ++j)
        A[i][j] = value;

  // Convert to a double[3][4]  ...
  double **convert = ???

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `double**` isn’t a “normal array” – it’s a double pointer. And although that’s possible, it’s not a good way to represent a 2D array in C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) See documentation  Boost MultiArray about member function  data():

> element* data();
>   const element* data() const;
>
> This returns a pointer to the beginning of the contiguous block that
>   contains the array's data. If all dimensions of the array are
>   0-indexed and stored in ascending order, this is equivalent to
>   origin(). Note that const_multi_array_ref only provides the const
>   version of this function.

Or

2) You can use multi_array_ref:

> multi_array_ref is a multi-dimensional container adaptor. It provides the MultiArray interface over any contiguous block of elements. multi_array_ref exports the same interface as multi_array, with the exception of the constructors.

But in any case - I think it is bad idea to copy data from  multi_array to C-array. If the reason is legacy code then see - http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/multi_array/doc/user.html#sec_storage